# The Application Default Credentials are not available in my Android APP even though the JSON file is in the RAW directory

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, google-cloud-platform, xamarin.forms

I am not concerned about secrurity and have stored my JSON credential file in the RAW directory of my Android APP and still get the error

> "The Application Default    Credentials are not available."

Why does this not function?

```
GoogleCredential MyCredential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);
```

where json is a character string including the json credentials file.

Comment: Have you verified that the json you are loading from the file is correct?

Comment: If you are not concerned about the security. Why do you use credential? Open your Google Cloud resources to `allUsers` and anyone can access them. By the way, adding a JSON file in a Android package is similar to let anyone accessing your resources. Indeed, the android archive are easy to unpack and your JSON file is not encrypted. Therefore, it's like having a secret publicly accessible. And so, it's no longer a secret if anyone know it!